# Why does this code behave differently in Python3.1 than in Python2.6?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

I'm very new to programming so I apologize in advance if my question is too silly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6  
import subprocess, time  
p=subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
for i in 'abcd':  
    p.stdin.write(str.encode(i+'\n'))  
    output=p.stdout.readline()  
    print(output)  
    time.sleep(1)
```

Executing this code in  Python 2.6 prints letters a, b, c, d , each line of output appears after a second. This is expected behavior. 
But in Python 3.1 execution is blocked at line `output=p.stdout.readline()`. 
How to correct this for Python 3.1?

Comment: what exactly happens when the execution is blocked? Do you have an error you could show?

Comment: not errors, only prompts for input; this code was executed in terminal window

Comment: At a guess it might be differences in buffering; does something change if you add a call to p.stdin.flush after the write?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer my question; adding p.stdin.flush() solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be a difference in buffering. Adding a `p.stdin.flush()` call solved the problem. (See the comments above).

Community wiki as I deserve no credits for this answer, but some answer needs to be marked accepted.

[@Geo Pop: Please "accept" this question, as it apparently is correct.]